# detect space in string

Tags: java, string, space

How do I determine if a space is in the input entered by the user? The user's input is stored in a string. The part I'm referring to is in between the asterisks. I read that regex could be used but I do not know how to use it to detect if there is a space in the string s.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class LAnalyze{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int j = 0;
    String s = null;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Enter an input:  ");
    s = scan.nextLine();

    ****************************************************
              Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    boolean found = matcher.find(); 

    if(spaceIsFound)
             *******************************************************
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid character(s) entered.. Program terminated!\n");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else if( s.charAt(0)=='a'||s.charAt(0)=='b'||s.charAt(0)=='c'||s.charAt(0)=='d'||s.charAt(0)=='e'||s.charAt(0)=='f'||
            s.charAt(0)=='g'||s.charAt(0)=='h'||s.charAt(0)=='i'||s.charAt(0)=='j'||s.charAt(0)=='k'||s.charAt(0)=='l'||
            s.charAt(0)=='m'||s.charAt(0)=='n'||s.charAt(0)=='o'||s.charAt(0)=='p'||s.charAt(0)=='q'||s.charAt(0)=='r'||
            s.charAt(0)=='s'||s.charAt(0)=='t'||s.charAt(0)=='u'||s.charAt(0)=='v'||s.charAt(0)=='w'||s.charAt(0)=='x'||
            s.charAt(0)=='y'||s.charAt(0)=='z'||s.charAt(0)=='A'||s.charAt(0)=='B'||s.charAt(0)=='C'||s.charAt(0)=='D'||
            s.charAt(0)=='E'||s.charAt(0)=='F'||s.charAt(0)=='G'||s.charAt(0)=='H'||s.charAt(0)=='I'||s.charAt(0)=='J'||
            s.charAt(0)=='K'||s.charAt(0)=='L'||s.charAt(0)=='M'||s.charAt(0)=='N'||s.charAt(0)=='O'||s.charAt(0)=='P'||
            s.charAt(0)=='Q'||s.charAt(0)=='R'||s.charAt(0)=='S'||s.charAt(0)=='T'||s.charAt(0)=='U'||s.charAt(0)=='V'||
            s.charAt(0)=='W'||s.charAt(0)=='X'||s.charAt(0)=='Y'||s.charAt(0)=='Z') {

        System.out.print( (s) + ": Identifier\n");
        for (int k = 0; k < s.length(); k++) {  
            j++;
            System.out.println("Token " + (j) + " = " + (s.charAt(k)));

        }
    }
    else if(s.charAt(0)=='0'||s.charAt(0)=='1'||s.charAt(0)=='2'||s.charAt(0)=='3'||s.charAt(0)=='4'||s.charAt(0)=='5'||
            s.charAt(0)=='6'||s.charAt(0)=='7'||s.charAt(0)=='8'||s.charAt(0)=='9') {

        System.out.print( (s) + ": Unsigned Integer\n");
        for (int m = 0; m < s.length(); m++) {  
            j++;
            System.out.println("Token " + (j) + " = " + (s.charAt(m)));
        }
    }   
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid character(s) entered.. Program terminated!\n");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Hint: chars can be interpreted as numbers so operators `<`, `<=`, `==`, `>`, `=>` can be used with them like `if ((s.charAt(0)>='a' && s.charAt(0)<='z')||(s.charAt(0)>='A' && s.charAt(0)<='Z'))`

Comment: Do you need to test if user has entered only spaces as the input or you want to erase all the spaces from left and right of the user input?

Answer (score 4):

You can use s.indexOf(' ');
If it returns -1 the string does not contain spaces.

Also, you can use
    switch(s.charAt(0)){
        case 'a':
        case 'b':
          ... 
        break;
        case 'c':
          ... 
    }

in place of the multiple if.

Comment: Thanks this was giving me a headache.

Comment: @user1781192 Remember to [*accept this answer*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking the checkmark if it solved your problem. That is SO's "thank you" mechanism :-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use regex just to check if string contains spaces. Use [String.contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead.